# Dynamically created form not posting ajax in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am working on eCommerce web application in laravel 5.

I have `products` table and `product_options` table, both have `One-To-Many` relationship established.

In the admin panel, I have provided the provision of dynamically adding the product options form on click of the button, which works fine.

But when posting the form using jquery ajax on click of the button, I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Here's the `route`:

```
Route::post('/admin/products/options', 'ProductsController@storeOptions');
```

The controller:

```
public function storeOptions(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'p_option_item_code' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:product_options',
        'p_option_details'   => 'string',
        'p_option_price'     => 'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/',
        'p_option_quantity'  => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    if ( $request->ajax() )
    {
        $request['product_id'] = Session::get('product_last_inserted_id');
        ProductOption::create( $request->all() );

        return response(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'The product option has been added successfully.']);
    }
    return response(['status' => 'failed', 'msg' => 'The product option could not be added successfully.']);
}
```

`form`: created dynamically using jquery

```
<div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="errors"></div>
    {!! Form::open(['url' => ['/admin/products/options'], 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'formAddProdOption']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('p_option_item_code', 'Item Code:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('p_option_item_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('p_option_details', 'Product Details:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('p_option_details', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'rows' => 3]) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('p_option_quantity', 'Stock:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('p_option_quantity', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
        </div>
        // other fields ...

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Add', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btnAddProdOption', 'id' => 'btnAddProdOption']) !!}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

`jquery` code:

```
$('.btnAddProdOption').on('click', function() {
    var inputData = $('#formAddProdOption').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/admin/products/options') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: inputData,
        success: function(m) {
            toastr.success(m.msg, 'Successs!');
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            if ( data.status === 422 ) {
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
                errorsHtml += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
                $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                    errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                });
                errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
                $( '.errors' ).html( errorsHtml );
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The click event is not getting fired at all. I don't the reason why is it not working.

Can anybody help me out ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the click event is not getting fired for a dynamically added form, it sounds like the event listener is added before the form itself is. Try using event delegation by attaching the listener to a parent element:

```
// instead of:
$('.btnAddProdOption').on('click', function() { }

// try:
$('body').on('click', '.btnAddProdOption', function() { }
```

`body` is just an example that would always work, since everything is in the body; in practice you'd want to attach it to whatever element is the closest parent of the form that doesn't dynamically change.

Comment: Thanks.. Your code did worked.. I don't know why this didn't clicked me at first. But thanks once again.